# Using different Proxies per page with Puppeteer

Tags: proxy, puppeteer

Set Proxy per page in a Puppeteer Browser

Using a For of loop to create a new page for each automated instance, but after both pages load and take a screenshot, whatever is the first instance to start automating first, it takes over and only that automation takes place.

setting flags from what i've seen is only doable when creating a new browser
eg.

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args:['--proxy-server=ip:port']});
```

cant seem to find any docs about setting it via the page.

Answer (score 3):

I made a module that does this. It's called [**puppeteer-page-proxy**](https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy).
It supports setting a proxy for an entire page, or if you like, it can set a different proxy for each request.

First install it:

```
npm i puppeteer-page-proxy
```

Then require it:

```js
const useProxy = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');
```

**Using it is easy;**
Set proxy for an entire page:

```js
await useProxy(page, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

If you want a different proxy for each request,then you can simply do this:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', req => {
    useProxy(req, 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9000');
});
```

Then if you want to be sure that your page's IP has changed, you can look it up;

```js
const data = await useProxy.lookup(page);
console.log(data.ip);
```

It supports **http**, **https**, **socks4** and **socks5** proxies, and it also supports authentication if that is needed:

```js
const proxy = 'http://login:pass@127.0.0.1:8000'
```

Repository:
https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy